# Replacing multiple feedback messages with one message in a Form with a ListView in wicket

Tags: validation, wicket, wicket-1.5

I have a webpage which picks up questions from a database and ask users to give an Yes/No questions and sometimes based on the question they have to select a dropdown list or a text to enter.

I need to mark the fields which are missing or invalid data is entered.  All the fields are mandatory so I am using setRequired(true); and using  Abstract behaviour class, I am adding a border to highlight the formcomponent ( Check Box or Dropdownlist) if it has any errors. If any fields are missing or invalid ,  I am displaying a generic error message - *Invalid or missing data! Please review the fields marked in red colour.*

I cannot display error messages next to the fields as I have less space around the component on the page.

I have achieved it by using a feedbackfilter for the Form and overriding the onError() method of the Form.  Since the feedback messages of formcomponents are not rendered on a feedbackpanel, I am getting the following warning in the console.

`WARN  WebSession : Component-targetted feedback message was left unrendered. This could be because you are missing a FeedbackPanel on the page.  Message: [FeedbackMessage message = "Field 'L2' is required.", reporter = L2, level = ERROR]`

Is there a way we can get rid of the messages and still retain the formcomponent as invalid ( **FormComponent.isVallid()** ) and a clean log files ?

I have tried clearing the feedback messages from session but it has an impact on the FormComponent Valid status.

I am on Wicket 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Make the feedback panel persistent invisible - there can be any messages and it still should not appear ...

Comment: I tried setting it using setVisible. But warning remains in the log